# Самовольно меняется значение в базе

Tags: mysql, autoincrement

Гуглил возможность `INSERT OR UPDATE` в базу. Нашёл. Написал пробный скрипт с только этой инструкцией.

```
$mysql_host = "localhost"; // sql сервер
$mysql_user = "***"; // пользователь
$mysql_password = "***"; // пароль
$mysql_database = "***"; // имя базы данных 
$conn = mysql_connect( $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password ); // коннект к серверу SQL
mysql_select_db( $mysql_database ); // коннект к БД на сервере
mysql_set_charset( 'utf-8' ); // кодировка

$query = "INSERT INTO userslist (`id`, `balance_m`) 
VALUES ('130', '130')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
balance_m='135'";
$result = mysql_query( $query, $conn );
```

Всё норм, создалась строка с `balance_m`=130.
Но, почему-то, в поле `count_zvon` проставилась 1.
Запустил ещё раз, `balance_m` стало 135, как и должно быть, всё работает.

`count_zvon` стал 2.
Запустил ещё раз, там стало 3.
И так каждый раз значение увеличивается на 1.
Там по умолчанию нет ничего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за мистика?
В триггерах нет ничего.

[image: В триггерах нет ничего.]

Comment: А в разделе "триггеры" точно ничего нет?

Comment: @Spatz, в триггерах нет ничего. В вопрос дописал.

Comment: Это говорит о том, что нет триггеров, которые может просмотреть текущая учётная запись. Посмотрите от рута (а ещё лучше - используя CLI, а не GUI-клиента).

Answer (score -1):

Простите все, оказывается был сбой на сервере, техподдержка всё пофиксила.